# How to concat to last item in array state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

say I have an array like this: `['uk', 'germany', 'spain']`

and then I want to concat onto the end of it but for every keystroke how would I do that?

so it could resemble the following:

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'f']`

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fr']`

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fra']`

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fran']`

etc

I was going to just get the value and then remove the last value in the array and append the new one so like

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fr']` // I would remove `fr` then add the next val, `fra` e.g.

problem is the first time it happens

`['uk', 'germany', 'spain']` if I did that here I would end up removing Spain

before you ask why am I doing it like this. I'm getting users to add random things they want to a list but they could feasibly save at any point so `['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fr']` would be perfectly valid in my use case

any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: What about just using `['uk', 'germany', 'spain', '']`?

Comment: why don't you change your list only after user finished typing what they need? of course there is one-liner for what you need: `['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fr'].slice(0, 3).concat('fra')`, where 3 is length of array - 1 and 'fra' is next value, so you can easily put everything into a function

Comment: @BlindDespair what about if my array is just `['uk']`? I guess I could do `['uk', 'germany', 'spain', 'fr'].slice(0, arr.length).concat('fra')`

Comment: well, for case your array is just `['uk']` I guess you want to add new element, right? then your user should define end of input for first element and define that it's anew one, I don't know the details of your app, e.g. they hit enter or something. Then you can call a different function, which concats the value without slicing. But then you could also add the item to array when user defines end of input. Because only user can know what they consider as finished input. From coding point of view we don't know if they'll type `uk` or `a horse`.

Comment: essentially I've got edit functionality. so it maps over all the "things". then they click edit and all the items are editable a new blank box pops up too. they click save to then save their details. if it's blank I don't want to add it to the saved view but if they add `a goose` for example it should then add to the array so the map then maps over that

Comment: it would be nice to see a screenshot or at least a drawing of your UI, because it's hard to imagine

Comment: manage new item separately, on save decide if add to an array

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of the requirement using `useState` hook on an input; that is written immutable-friendly manner; that `3` number is hard-coded but can be dynamic as well.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root);

function App(){
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState(['uk', 'germany', 'spain']);
  
  function changeHandler(e){
    if(countries[3]){
      let countriesCopy = countries.slice(0);
      countriesCopy[3] = e.target.value;
      setCountries(countriesCopy)
    }else{
      setCountries(countries.concat(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  return(
    <input onChange={changeHandler} value={countries[3]} />
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have users typing

```
 "ukgermanyspainfra"
```

if you want to  add them as

```
["uk","germany"... ]
```

You should have mechanism to seperate different items which could be a button or you could ask users to use "," to seperate elements if they are inputting all the countries to a single input element. Then you can apply the solution you suggested for removing "fr" at the end of array then adding "fra" to end of array.